# covington gloss in multicolumn in a Beamer slide ... randomly inserted line

Tags: beamer, linguistics, covington

My wife is trying to create a presentation for her PhD linguistics class and the minimal example I have here is:

```
\documentclass[american,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Slide 1}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \gll Richard je hladový.
        Richard is hungry
        \glt 'Richard is hungry.'
        \glend
    \columnbreak{}
        \gll Richard má hlad.
        Richard has hunger
        \glt 'Richard is hungry.'
        \glend
    \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which unfortunately leads to this:

[image]

Notice how the second example has inserted line before the translation line.
Anybody any idea how to avoid this superfluous line? Is there any better method how to make a tableaux with two glosses (normal LaTeX table didn't work and multicolumn as a workaround has been suggested here on the StackExchange)?

Thank you

Comment: What's the reason for `multicols` rather the `column` feature of `beamer`? Anyway, I don't get the wrong spacing from the presented code.

Comment: @egreg YES! The reason is I am an idiot and the Beamer User Guide is too long for my small brain. Make this answer into proper Answer, so I can approve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the standard Beamer `columns` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{covington}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Slide 1}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \gll Richard je hladový.
        Richard is hungry
        \glt 'Richard is hungry.'
        \glend
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
        \gll Richard má hlad.
        Richard has hunger
        \glt 'Richard is hungry.'
        \glend
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]